# how to add elements dict to dataframe using python?

Tags: python, dataframe

### i want to add a data from dict to dataframe and display on table is possible ??

```
import pandas as pd
names = ['alan','jack','martin','loki','edward','sakes']
old = [18,17,20,21,22,19]

data = {'names':names,'old':old}
print(data)
```

### after excute :

```
{'names': ['alan', 'jack', 'martin', 'loki', 'edward', 'sakes'], 'old': [18, 17, 20, 21, 22, 19]}
```

---

> any solution possible ??

***plz help me i need for us***

Comment: Is `data = pd.DataFrame({'names': names, 'old': old})` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell whether you want column-oriented or row-oriented.

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ cat x.py
import pandas as pd
names = ['alan','jack','martin','loki','edward','sakes']
old = [18,17,20,21,22,19]
print( pd.DataFrame( [old], columns=names ) )
print( pd.DataFrame( {'names': names, 'old':old } ) )
```

Output:

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ python x.py
   alan  jack  martin  loki  edward  sakes
0    18    17      20    21      22     19
    names  old
0    alan   18
1    jack   17
2  martin   20
3    loki   21
4  edward   22
5   sakes   19
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite simple:

```
pd.DataFrame([data])
```

That should do the trick